# Modify Header Height In Datatable in R For Shiny Dashboard

Tags: css, r, shinydashboard

I am trying to tighten the height of the header of my datatable in R. I am referencing the header as part of the initComplete=JS() argument.

Below is the snippet of my code:

initComplete=JS("function(settings, json) {","$(this.api().table().header()).css({'text-align': 'center','font-size': '95%', 'height': '10%'}),"}")

While this works for the text-align and font-size pieces, the header height is not changing regardless of what I put in. Am I missing something here? Any help would be really appreciated